# An ice cube containing a metallic ball in it is floating in a vessel containing water. When the ice melts, what happens to the level of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I understand the fact that if there was no metallic ball in it, then when the ice melts, the level of water would neither rise nor fall. Now let us consider the case where there is a metallic ball in it. When the ice melts, the volume  of water added to the vessel would be less than the volume displaced by the ice structure when it was floating. This should mean that the water level will fall if i am not mistaken, further which the metallic ball would sink. When that happens, it is displacing the same amount of volume as it did when it was within the ice. So shouldn't it mean that the water level would fall ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before : the equilibrium of forces tells you that the displaced volume of water is $V=[m_{\text{ice}}+m_{\text{ball}}]/[\rho_{\text{water}}]$ (equilibrium of forces). After, the volume is $V'=m_{\text{ice}}/\rho_{\text{water}}+m_{\text{ball}}/\rho_{\text{steel}}$ (volume additivity). Clearly $V'<V$ because $\rho_{\rm steel }>\rho_{\rm water}$. The volume of water falls.